# File.exists() doesn't work

Tags: r

I have to be either blind or stupid, but I cannot move forward with this:

I have a variable sourceName defined as:

```
sourceName = file.path(dataDatabase, dates[1], paste0(exchange, "_", ticker, "_trade.csv"))
```

which is this string:

```
 "/home/malejg/goxtrader/data/2014-12-12/Bitfinex_BTC_trade.csv"
```

When I check the existenece of the file, I got the following result:

```
> file.exists(sourceName)
> [1] TRUE
```

so the file definitely exists. But when I use the above code in the if statement going like:

```
 if(file.exists(sourceName)){
    some sample code here}
```

it throws an error:

```
 Error in if (file.exists(sourceName)) { : argument is of length zero
```

How is it possible?
The code works fine on Windows, so is there some Linux related problem?

**SESSION INFO:**

> sessionInfo()  R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) Platform:
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8      [5]
>   LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8     [7]
>   LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                   [9]
>   LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11]
>   LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] data.table_1.9.4 xts_0.9-7
>   zoo_1.7-11
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] chron_2.3-45
>   grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-30 plyr_1.8.1      [5] Rcpp_0.11.5
>   reshape2_1.4.1  stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.1.2

Comment: Are you sure the error is attributed to the `file.exists` returning an object of length zero?  have you tried a trivial block like `if (file.exists(sourceName))print('hello world')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use isTRUE()

```
if (isTRUE(file.exists(sourceName))) {
    cat('Found')
}
```

Comment: But why is it necessary?

Comment: I would also like to see an explanation, because in my tests I cannot reproduce the OP's error, and so AFAICT `isTRUE` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: It would be good to see the smallest codeset that demonstrates the actual problem.  Note: The isTRUE function will return a false for an empty vector. A zero length vector was also the only way I could make an "if" statement return the OP's original error message.

Comment: @joran: What oS are you working on? My initial code worked pretty well on Windows but threw the error above on Ubuntu. I know it is weird but the above removed the error. I can provide a reproducible example, but as it works with files and directories, you would have to have the same files.

Comment: @SteefGregor I'm on OS X. The part that seems weird to me is not that `isTRUE` "worked" but that `file.exists` returned a vector of length zero in the first place. My initial reaction to that would be that it is at least undocumented behavior, and maybe a bug. If you can demonstrate `file.exists` returning an empty vector reproducibly, that would be an interesting question on it's own, I think.

Comment: @SteefGregor: How about a single file name in the current directory?  I can make sure it does or does not exist, as required.  (Note: I'm working in Debian Linux, but I can fire up my Windows if it's useful.)

Answer (score 5):

This is an extremely speculative answer...

I can get `file.exists` to return a logical vector of zero length only as follows:

```
> file.exists(character(0))
logical(0)
```

So my tentative hypothesis is that you mistakenly wiped that variable that should have been a file path and passed a zero length character vector to `file.exists` by mistake.

This would imply that `isTRUE` *is* the safest option in one sense, but personally I can hardly think of a case where passing a zero length vector to `file.exists` would be intentional on my part, and I'd probably want to see that error and fix it.

Comment: `dataDatabase` could be NULL.  `file.path(NULL, "foo.bar")` returns `character(0)`