# File x doesn't exist but if(file.exists(x)) readRDS(x) attempts to read x

Tags: r

I want to read a bunch of files in from a directory using a loop, with a set naming convention (e.g., `File_a_1.Rds`, `File_a_2.Rds`, `File_b_1.Rds`, etc.). There might be gaps in the file names (e.g., `File_a_2.Rds` might be missing), but gaps themselves aren't a problem. To account for gaps, I've tried using `file.exists()`: `if (file.exists(fname)) readRDS(fname) else NULL`, but I then get an error message indicating that R tried to do `readRDS(fname)` even though `fname` doesn't exist: `Error in readRDS(fname) : error reading from connection`. What's going on here?

Other means of testing this if-statement indicate that it works when I'm not trying to use `readRDS()`. For example, `if (file.exists(fname)) "apple" else "banana"` gives me apples and bananas where I expect them, so it's weird that the same logic isn't applied to `if (file.exists(fname)) readRDS(fname) else NULL`. Likewise, using `ifTRUE()` doesn't help things, contra [an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083693/file-exists-doesnt-work).

N.B. The type of loop shouldn't matter, but in this case I'm using `mclapply()` to vectorize the operation. And normally I'd just do something like `dir() %>% do.call(readRDS)`, but then the files would be in the wrong order and without the nested structure I'm looking for.

Session info:

````
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_NZ.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_NZ.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_NZ.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_NZ.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_NZ.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_NZ.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_NZ.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DMwR_0.4.1      ROCR_1.0-7      gplots_3.0.1.1  caret_6.0-81    lattice_0.20-38 ranger_0.11.1  
 [7] lmerTest_3.1-0  lme4_1.1-20     Matrix_1.2-15   magrittr_1.5    forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0  
[13] dplyr_0.8.0.1   purrr_0.3.0     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.2     tibble_2.0.1    ggplot2_3.1.0  
[19] tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-137       bitops_1.0-6       xts_0.11-2         lubridate_1.7.4    httr_1.4.0        
 [6] numDeriv_2016.8-1  tools_3.5.2        backports_1.1.3    R6_2.4.0           rpart_4.1-13      
[11] KernSmooth_2.23-15 lazyeval_0.2.1     colorspace_1.4-0   nnet_7.3-12        withr_2.1.2       
[16] tidyselect_0.2.5   curl_3.3           compiler_3.5.2     cli_1.0.1          rvest_0.3.2       
[21] xml2_1.2.0         caTools_1.17.1.1   scales_1.0.0       digest_0.6.18      minqa_1.2.4       
[26] rmarkdown_1.11     base64enc_0.1-3    pkgconfig_2.0.2    htmltools_0.3.6    TTR_0.23-4        
[31] rlang_0.3.1        readxl_1.3.0       rstudioapi_0.9.0   quantmod_0.4-13    generics_0.0.2    
[36] zoo_1.8-4          jsonlite_1.6       gtools_3.8.1       ModelMetrics_1.2.2 Rcpp_1.0.0        
[41] munsell_0.5.0      abind_1.4-5        stringi_1.3.1      yaml_2.2.0         MASS_7.3-51.1     
[46] plyr_1.8.4         recipes_0.1.4      gdata_2.18.0       crayon_1.3.4       haven_2.1.0       
[51] splines_3.5.2      hms_0.4.2          knitr_1.21         pillar_1.3.1       reshape2_1.4.3    
[56] codetools_0.2-16   stats4_3.5.2       glue_1.3.0         evaluate_0.13      data.table_1.12.0 
[61] modelr_0.1.4       nloptr_1.2.1       foreach_1.4.4      cellranger_1.1.0   gtable_0.2.0      
[66] assertthat_0.2.0   xfun_0.5           gower_0.1.2        prodlim_2018.04.18 broom_0.5.1       
[71] class_7.3-15       survival_2.43-3    timeDate_3043.102  iterators_1.0.10   lava_1.6.5        
[76] ipred_0.9-8       ```
````

Comment: It may be the way your script is written. Please provide the example that causes the unusual behaviour. Describing it inline as you have may conceal something about the formatting that induces the error.

Comment: we're probably not going to be able to debug this without a reproducible example ...

Comment: `if(file.exists(f)) readRDS(f) else NULL` on my machine reads `f` when it exists and returns NULL when it doesn't, so I don't think that is the issue. There is something about your loop or environment causing the problem.